# Kernel Panic when launching Ubuntu-Mate 16

Tags: ubuntu

I have a Raspberry Pi Model B+ V1.2 and I have been trying to load Ubuntu-Mate to the Raspberry as its operating system. I am not the most experienced with Raspberry, a mere beginner. Therefore, I downloaded the image for Ubuntu-Mate and loaded it to a 8GB microSDHC card(format is MS-DOS FAT16) using Etcher.

It loads successfully onto the SD card, according to Etcher, and then I connect my Raspberry to its power source and connect an HDMI cable from the TV to the Raspberry. However, it gets stuck on the loading screen:

[image: Photo of startup screen]

Sorry for the low quality image, but I don't know where to get the logs from and since I am not doing this on a virtual machine, but on my TV, I don't know how to copy and paste them.

Why is it giving me this error and what can I do to fix it to launch the operating system?

Comment: "what can I do to fix it to launch the operating system?" Buy a Pi3!

Answer (score 3):

The Raspberry Pi B+ uses an ARMv6 based processor while the newer Pi 2 and 3 models run on an ARMv7 and ARMv8 based CPUs, respectively. Unfortunately, this means you won't be able to install Ubuntu MATE on your B+ Pi, as per [this post](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/ubuntu-mate-15-04-possible-on-original-pi-b-v1-2-not-newer-2-mod-b/1497) on the Ubuntu forums.

I have never used one of the older B+ models like the one you have, but I'd imagine following the the NOOBS installer [tutorial](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/noobs-setup/2/) will let you install a compatible version of Raspbian that will boot just fine.

Comment: Is there any place where I can check what operatinnsystem my raspberry supports? Could it support arch Linux?

Comment: [This page](https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv6/raspberry-pi)  on the Arch wiki mentions a link to [download](http://os.archlinuxarm.org/os/ArchLinuxARM-rpi-latest.tar.gz) a .img file, that might be what you're looking for. Again, I've never used a Pi B+ nor Arch Linux for any raspberry Pi so that's all I can really say besides good luck ;)